# android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity can not be resolved

Tags: android

I'm trying to open the mapdemo sample project included in the google play services. However, it is giving me errors in every src file all boiling down to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; can not be resolved. How do I fix this? Did I skip a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the support library to your project.

Right Click in your project -> Android Tools -> Add support library